# If we are finding the Thevinin equivalence of the following circuit, Are the inductor and the capacitor in series?

Tags: circuit-analysis, passive-networks, thevenin, norton

[image]

If we are finding the Thevinin equivalence of the following circuit, Are the inductor and the capacitor in series? I should be looking from the 36 OHM resistor right?

Comment: why can't you be bothered to spell Thevenin's name correctly?

Comment: No. When two items are in series, the current through them is the same. Because of the current source, the current in the inductor is not the same as in the capcitor.

Comment: @mkeith But the OP is looking for the equivalent of the entire circuit, what currents are shared inside this circuit is none of interest. So my answer is : yes, they are connected in series, as the current source has infinite internal resistance.

Comment: They are in series or not in series (the latter is the case) independetly if you are finding the Thevenin equivalence or not. Therefore I don't understand you question.

Comment: It doesn't matter. Just solve the circuit for open circuit voltage, and the impedance seen looking into ab with the current source open circuited.

Comment: The original circuit is solved in this youtube video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5SSYtwjtUO0
This video solves it all.

Answer (score 0):

Two elements are in series if they share exactly one common node, and no other elements are connected to that common node. The inductor and capacitor share one common node, but there is a third element connected to that node (the current source). So they are not in series in the given circuit. However, if the current source were replaced with an open circuit, then they would be in series.

There are two ways I know of to calculate the Thévenin equivalent circuit. First, calculate both Isc and Voc. The Thévenin circuit is then Voc in series with an impedance of Voc/Isc.

The second way is to calculate Voc, and then "kill" all the independent sources, and calculate the impedance looking in to the resulting network. Killing sources consists of replacing all independent current sources with an open-circuit, and replacing all independent voltage sources with a short circuit.

So if we do this circuit the second way, then it would be necessary to replace the current source with an open-circuit. At that point, the capacitor and inductor would be effectively in series.

Without the current source being specified, it is not possible to actually solve the problem. But if the current source is a DC source, then Voc is 0V, and the Thévenin equivalent circuit is passive, with no voltage source.

Comment: For thevenin resistance calculation they are in series as current source will be seen as open.

Comment: @sarthak: (1) There is more than one way to find the Thevenin source equivalent of a circuit. (2) Whether two components are in series or not never depends on *how* you look at a circuit (when you "see" something "as open" you aren't looking at the same circuit any more. You have changed the circuit; or you are seeing wrong). (3) I don't know how "seeing" the current source as open helps finding the Thevenin equivalent

Comment: @Curd I don't know how you calculate it but when we normally calculate Thevenin resistance of a network, we null all the independent sources to zero, and zero current means open circuit.  This is a consequence of superposition theorem.

Comment: I've edited my answer. Hopefully the downvoters will reconsider.

Comment: The way I was taught was to find Voc and Isc. Thévenin equivalent is a source with value Voc and series resistance of Voc/Isc. But in this circuit, Voc and Isc are both zero, so that procedure doesn't work. The backup procedure for finding R is to "kill the sources" and calculate impedance looking in at the reference nodes.

Comment: @mkeith: Why do you think Voc and Isc are zero? (This is only the case if the source is a DC source; but if this is the case the whole problem is trivial). Just assume a sinusoidal source and use impedances...

Comment: @sarthak: e.g. like mkeith said: calculate Voc and Isc, etc.

Comment: @sarthak, that is true. Will try to re-edit later.

Answer (score 0):

If we want to find out the open terminal resistance trough the circuit... 1st we will short the circuit by removing the current sourse and open circuit bybremoving the voltage sourse, then our inductor will be use less.... so after all we will got tha resistor and capacitor is conected in pparallel....

Comment: If current sources were shorted internally, they wouldn't be "source" at all, can you see why?

Comment: You have it backwards. To calculate impedance, you replace independent current sources with open circuits, and replace independent voltage sources with short circuits.

Comment: @Diljeet Gunesani : There is a thevenin, norton webpage the says we open circuit the voltage source and short circuit the current source, but i can gurantee you that's wrong. Quit the opposite is right. The web page is http://alan.ece.gatech.edu/ECE3040/Lectures/CircuitReview.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Assuming current source to be ideal (and thus having infinite internal resistance), yes, looking from terminals 'a' & 'b', inductor and capacitor will be in series.

There is no rule that from where you should be looking into circuit, you get the equivalent circuit between those terminals from where you choose to see.

Do you want to find current through resistor? If that's the case, which terminals would you choose such that Thevenin's equivalent circuit would help the most?